# Count Nested Select Result And Sum up- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The first *SELECT* for example returns 57 and 61. I want the second sql command to use returned rows of first *SELECT* not like what I have put here (manually 57 and 61). Finally calculate *sum* of these results. (9 is the result of course)

```
1. SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE title = 'samplezip'   
2. SELECT count(id) FROM accesslogs WHERE urlid=57 AND status='d' //result 7  
3. SELECT count(id) FROM accesslogs WHERE urlid=61 AND status='d' //result 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM accesslogs 
WHERE status = 'd'
  AND urlid IN (SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE title = 'samplezip');
```

For a result row per ID plus a total use `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT urlid, count(*)
FROM accesslogs 
WHERE status = 'd'
  AND urlid IN (SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE title = 'samplezip')
GROUP BY urlid WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in one i think:

```
select
    count(l.id)
from
    permissions as p
    inner join accesslogs as l
        on p.id = l.urlid
where 
    p.title = 'samplezip'
    and status ='d'
```

Comment: Oh, Now it gives two rows. not calculated sum! Before group by it was correct.

Comment: @MessiMeysam i have rolled back the changes made in gordatron's answer, just also ignore `p.title, p.id` from select part these values will be returned in in-deterministic  order